# If no other gauge theory besides $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ exists, is the Clay Problem on Yang-Mills theory solved?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills

If no other gauge theory besides $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ exists, is the [Clay Problem on Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap) solved? It appears that there are several possible answers. Which one is the best one?

- A. If no other gauge groups exist in nature, the problem has no interest any more, even if such groups exist mathematically.
- B. If other gauge groups are possible in mathematics, but not in nature, the problem is still interesting.
- C. If other gauge groups are neither possible in mathematics nor in nature, the problem is still interesting, because the mass gap still needs to be proven for $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$.

Or is some other answer even better?

Answer (score 2):

The Clay problem is a purely mathematical one. It has nothing to do with whether gauge groups exist in nature. There are an infinite number of gauge theories with compact simple groups other than $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$, and the problem includes all of them.

The problem has remained unsolved for twenty years.

Comment: That would mean that answer B. is closest?

Comment: If I had to pick one, yes. But even if the problem were, say, just for $SU(3)$, it would *still* be unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

The official problem description is [1]:

> ### Yang–Mills Existence and Mass Gap.
>
> *Prove that for any compact simple gauge group $G$, a non-trivial quantum Yang–Mills theory exists on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and has a mass gap $\Delta > 0$. Existence includes establishing axiomatic properties at least as strong as
>   those cited in* [2,3].

It explicitly doesn't care about $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ and even more explicitly it doesn't care whether other gauge groups exist in nature or not.

Furthermore, existence is mostly a constraint on the rigour of defining what a QFT is. The real physical value of the problem is the mass gap.

---

[1] A. Jaffe and E. Witten, *Quantum Yang-Mills Theory*, http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/yangmills.pdf

[2] K. Osterwalder and R. Schrader, *Axioms for Euclidean Green’s functions*, Comm. Math. Phys. **31** (1973), 83, and Comm. Math. Phys. **42** (1975), 281.

[3] R. Streater and A. Wightman, *PCT, Spin and Statistics and all That*, W. A. Benjamin, New York, 1964.

Comment: So the term "mass gap" is a purely mathematical one: it is meant as a mathematical quantity that can be defined even if the gauge group (say SU(4), for example) and the relevant particles do not exist in nature. Correct?

Comment: 'Mass gap' is simply the lowest possible positive eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian.